# Determining if a date field presents a calendar popup via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html, calendar

For an MVC app I am working on, we have some date fields on a page.

My initial reaction was to use jQuery UI's datepicker, but we hit a small snag - we're also expecting this application to be run on iPads.  So, I was asked to look into using the HTML5 `<input type="date" />` tag, but to fall back to the datepicker if the browser dosen't support it.

One additional small problem: IE is **evil.**

Apparently, IE *does* 'support' `<input type="date" />`; it just dosen't show the calendar when clicked.

A abbreviated, sanitized markup:

```
@* In the HTML body... *@
@Html.InputFor(m => m.SomeDate, new { id="A", type="date" })
@Html.InputFor(m => m.SomeOtherDate, new { id="B", type="date" })

<script>
var $A = $('#A'),
    $B = $('#B');

$(document).ready(function () {
  fallbackToDatepicker($A);
  fallbackToDatepicker($B);

  @* ...SNIP: Other operations here... *@
});

function fallbackToDatepicker($field) {
  if($field.type() != "date") {
    console.log($field.selector + " is not a date field!");
    $field.datepicker();
  }
}
</script>
```

(Solution based on: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml)

The problem I am trying to solve is to determine if the client is running a browser that does not have a native calendar popup for `<input type="date" />`; if the client is running on such a browser, I need to fallback to the datepicker.

**Question**: What would be a more accurate, but still elegant/programmatic way of determining if the client browser supports the date popup?

(A note: I am recommending my team abandon the date-input silliness, and just use the datepicker.)

Comment: Have you tried Modernizr, especially the test for an inputtype of date, or does IE lie?

Comment: IE totally lies.  No easy escape by Modernizr.

Comment: Try this [link](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: @PiLHA - While I can't deny that Twitter Bootstrap has a good date/time picker, that dosen't help with my actual question.